# Using hasManyThrough where target table has one-to-one

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

If we take [Laravels example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) on `hasManyThrough` and change it a like this:

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    website_id - integer
    name - string

websites
    id - integer
    title - string
```

Having `users` as the intermediate relation, can I use `hasManyThrough()` on `country` model to get `websites`?

I tried this and it results in an error

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the websites for the country.
     */
    public function websites()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Website', 'App\User');
    }
}
```

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column`

Maybe `users` must have many `websites` for this to work?

Comment: You are missing a foreign key `user_id` in table `websites`. Also there is no need to have website_id in `users` table.

Comment: @Samir But in my example a `user` can only have one `website`. Should I still add the foreign key to `websites`?

Comment: The way `hasManyThrough` works, you will have to do it. Here's the explaination picked up from the documentation: `Though posts does not contain a country_id column, the hasManyThrough relation provides access to a country's posts via $country->posts. To perform this query, Eloquent inspects the  country_id on the intermediate users table. After finding the matching user IDs, they are used to query the posts table.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the table structure to match Laravel's expectation per @Samir's comments, or you can customize the keys to match your existing table structure.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

> Typical Eloquent foreign key conventions will be used when performing the relationship's queries. If you would like to customize the keys of the relationship, you may pass them as the third and fourth arguments to the hasManyThrough method. The third argument is the name of the foreign key on the intermediate model. The fourth argument is the name of the foreign key on the final model. The fifth argument is the local key, while the sixth argument is the local key of the intermediate model:

```php
public function websites()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Website', 'App\User','country_id','id','website_id','website_id');
}
```

Comment: it worked! Just had to modify it a little `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Website', 'App\User','country_id','id','website_id','website_id');`